# How to transfer data from VM on vSphere to local system?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, esxi, data-transfer, vsphere

I have an vSphere ESXi with several virtual machines on it.
One of these VMs is an WindowsServer2008R2.
On this VM I have some data. These data should be transfered to my local system.
But I am not able to share a folder because the VM and the local system are in different nets.
Do you have an idea how I could manage that?
Thanks for trying to help me...

Answer (score 0):

You could...

- Setup the network so that they can route to each other and use a smb share
- Use ftp/sftp/some other form of communication with a direct routed network
- Copy the data onto a 'spare' vm (via the above means, or via a disk you attach to one system, remove it, attach it to another system... and then put this 'spare' vm on the correct network to be accessed
- If you have usb passthrough support, you can copy to a usb drive
- some more ideas [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2036993)

Answer (score 0):

Download the VM with VMware Workstation or the vSphere Client, and mount the VMDK with vmware-mount.exe obtained from the following link.

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/